# Segmentation fault in linux driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write a linux driver. The kernel version is 2.4.18 and the distribution is Red Hat linux 8.0.

The code of my driver is:

```
#define LINUX

#include <linux/kernel.h> /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/module.h> /* Specifically, a module */
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm-i386/semaphore.h>
#include "rng.h"
#include <linux/random.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#define DEVICE_NAME "rng"
#define BUF_LEN 80

static int major;
int init_module();
void cleanup_module();
static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);

struct file_operations my_fops = {
  open: device_open,
  release: device_release,
};


/* Init and Cleanup */

int init_module() {
   SET_MODULE_OWNER(&my_fops);
   major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &my_fops);
   return 0;
}

void cleanup_module() {

   int ret = unregister_chrdev(major, DEVICE_NAME);
   if (ret < 0)
       printk("Error in unregister_chrdev: %d\n", ret);

}

static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
   file->f_op=&my_fops;
   return 1;
}

static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
   return 0;
}
```

And the code I'm using in order to test my driver is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int openTest() {
    int game1 = open("/dev/game1", O_RDONLY); // SEGMENTATION FAULT
    int retValue=1;

    close(game1);
    return retValue;
}

int main() {
    int res;
    if (openTest() < 1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "open didnt work\n");
    return -1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "everything works :)\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, I'm getting a segmentation fault when I'm trying to open the device. Can somebody explain to me why I'm getting this segmentation fault? I really don't understand.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: does such device exists on your system?

Comment: @Nullpointer: Wouldn't that raise an `ENODEV` error instead of a segmentation one?

Comment: No but I'm creating a file with mknod that represents it

Comment: @chrk..I haven't really tried it...but I thought it can be a point of failure!

Comment: Why do you try to open `"game1"` when your driver creates `"rng"`?

Comment: Kernel version `2.4.18`? *Why?*

Comment: `int openTest(void)` and `int main(void)`. It's not the source of your segfault but the kernel uses C and not C++. There's a non negligible difference in C between `()` and `(void)`.

Comment: *Don't write kernel drivers* before being very familiar with [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf). If you really need to write a kernel driver, code it for a *recent* kernel. Current [kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) is 4.14 in December 2017. Your 2.4 kernel is more than ten years old, don't bother about it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: 1. This question was asked as part of an assignment at the time and writing the driver for 2.4 was mandatory. 2. I became familiar with Kernel Programming and Debugging and writing PoC drivers helped a lot in the learning process. Your "Don't write kernel drivers" advice is definitely a terrible one.

Comment: Did you read all the sentence.... I also wrote *before being*....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux kernel land, it is convention to return a 0 (zero) when there are no errors. Your device_open() routine is hardcoded to return a 1 (one), which may be causing your segfault.

[This Linux Device Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html#t5) book may be helpful to you. The linked edition is written for kernel 2.0.x - 2.4.x, so the information should be appropriate for the dusty and ancient kernel you are using.

Answer (score -1):

This line seems to be wrong `file->f_op=&my_fops;`

Basically when writing a **linux** driver operations are setup at build time itself.